# $\sqrt2^{\sqrt3 }$ $<$ $\sqrt3^{\sqrt2 }$ geometrical way

Tags: geometry, radicals, geometric-construction

From the pythagorean theorem we can construct the lengths $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$

Is it possible to construct the lengths $\sqrt2^{\sqrt3 }$ and $\sqrt3^{\sqrt2 }$
in order to show ( geometrically ) that:

$\sqrt2^{\sqrt3 }$ $<$ $\sqrt3^{\sqrt2 }$

thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think those numbers are algebraic.

Comment: no, there is no mechanism for exponentiating lengths using compass and straightedge. If we fix a length to be called $1,$ we can multiply and divide numbers, in particular we can square a length or cube it, but not raise to an irrational power. Put another way, there is no construction for logarithm.

Comment: oh, those items will be transcendental by Gelfond-Schneider.

Comment: At least no construction using "classical" methods and exact lengths, but there might be a brief clever way of approximating   $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ by rationals to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 5):

It is sufficient to demonstrate that the following are true:

$$1 < \sqrt 2 < e$$

$$1 < \sqrt 3 < e$$

$$ \sqrt 2 < \sqrt 3$$

These can be demonstrated geometrically as long as you are happy that $e>2$.

Having established the above geometrically, we can continue using calculus and algebra.

Consider $f(x)=\frac {\ln x}x$

$f'(x)=\frac 1{x^2}-\frac {\ln x}{x^2}$

$f'(x)=\frac {1-\ln x}{x^2}$

For $1<x<e$, we know that $0<\ln x <1 $

This means that $1-\ln x>0$ so $f'(x)>0$ - the function is increasing.

Since the function is increasing, $a<b \Rightarrow f(a)<f(b)$

$\sqrt 2<\sqrt 3 \Rightarrow f(\sqrt 2)<f(\sqrt 3)$

$\frac {\ln \left(\sqrt 2 \right)}{\sqrt 2}<\frac {\ln \left(\sqrt 3 \right)}{\sqrt 3}$

${\sqrt 3}{\ln \left(\sqrt 2 \right)}<{\sqrt 2}{\ln \left(\sqrt 3 \right)}$

${\ln \left({\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 3} \right)}<{\ln \left({\sqrt 3}^{\sqrt 2} \right)}$

${{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 3}}<{{\sqrt 3}^{\sqrt 2}}$ as required.

Comment: Actually used was calculus, not only algebra.

Comment: @coffeemath OK fixed to include calculus in my answer.